# Import module functions as staticmethods into a class

Tags: python, oop

I have a python module 
**helpers.py**

```py
def str_to_num(s: str):
    '''Converts to int if possible else converts to float if possible
    Returns back the string if not possible to convert to a number.
    '''
    # NOTE: These are not really funcs, but classes.
    funcs = [int, float]

    for func in funcs:
        try:
            res = func(s)
            break
        except ValueError:
            continue
    else:
        res = s

    return(res)
```

I have another module **string_number.py**

```py
from helpers import str_to_num

class StringNumber:

    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s

    str_to_num = str_to_num

    @property
    def value(self):
        return(self.str_to_num(self.s))

    def __repr__(self):
        return(f'{self.__class__.__name__}({repr(self.s)})')
```

```py
>>> from string_number import StringNumber
>>> sn = StringNumber(1)
>>> sn.value 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "string_number.py", line 19, in value
    return(self.str_to_num(self.s))
TypeError: str_to_num() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

However this works when accessing the function from the class:

```py
>>> StringNumber.str_to_num(1)
1
```

**Q.1**: Why does the `str_to_num` attribute require two arguments when accessing it from the instance? Is **self** being passed to it? If so, why?

Now, I know I can add modify the `__init__` method to make it an attribute of the instance

```py
def __init__(self, s):
    self.s = s
    self.str_to_num = str_to_num
```

Further, I can resolve this by making a class of Helper functions and then inheriting from it.

```py
from helpers import str_to_num

class Helper:
    @staticmethod
    def str_to_num(s):
        return(str_to_num(s))


class StringNumber(Helper):

    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s

    @property
    def value(self):
        return(self.str_to_num(self.s))

    def __repr__(self):
        return(f'{self.__class__.__name__}({repr(self.s)})')
```

**Q: 2** Is there a way to make module functions, staticmethods of a class, without using inheritance? Or is this a really bad practice?

**Q: 3** Assuming I had a **helpers.py** module, with a large amount of module functions. To incorporate them as staticmethods into my class, what would be the best way, without making a separate `Helper` class?

Answer (score 0):

> Q.1: Why does the str_to_num attribute require two arguments when accessing it from the instance? Is self being passed to it? If so, why?

You wrote "However this works when accessing the function from the class: `StringNumber.str_to_num(1)`". It works because you declared your method as a static method by defining it under your class definition.

As contrary to static method, instance method does pass the instance as a first argument when it's called. So when you called `instance.str_to_num(1)` your `str_to_num(s: str)` - no matter your type hinted it as a string - received instance as `s` argument and complained that value `1` hasn't got variable to hold it.

Comment: When I the doing the following:
```
class StringNumber:

    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s

    str_to_num = str_to_num

```
I am **NOT** defining ```str_to_num``` as a ```staticmethod```, it's just an attribute pointing to some ```object``` which is a function. My question is, why does it act as a ```staticmethod```, when I call it from the ```class```, but not when I call it from the ```instance```?

Comment: That attribute is a callable and you assigned it on the class level and so you bound it to the **class**. When you make a definition like `def foo(self):` inside a class then you bound it to the **instance**.